# Cpp Contentfunction out of thread using shared Queue

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, member-functions

I just started to work with cpp again after using python. I have a question regarding threads.
Setup: A main method that creates an object containing consumer function as well as the producer function. I would like to run them independet of each other as a two threads or three threads for additional consumer or producer. (See. the Classes). From the setup I think I understood the Topic of threads however I dont understand the error I got since I am not used that much to cpp threading.

ERROR:

> error C2893: Funktionsvorlage "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()" konnte nicht spezialisiert werden
>   xthread(237): note: Mit den folgenden Vorlagenargumenten:
>
> xthread(237): note: "_Callable=void (__thiscall Worker_Consumer::*
>   )(std::mutex &,std::condition_variable
>   &,std::deque> &)"
>
> xthread(237): note: "_Types={std::mutex *, std::condition_variable *,
>   std::deque> *}"

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "CAN_MESSAGE.h"
#include <bitset>
#include <thread>
#include "Worker_Consumer.h"
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>


int main()
{
    //sendMessage();
    std::deque<int> sharedQ;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable convar;

    std::thread t1(&Worker_Consumer::startProducer,&mtx,&convar, &sharedQ);
    std::thread t2(&Worker_Consumer::startConsumer,&mtx, &convar, &sharedQ);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

As well as my header file (just for testing i direktly coded it inside).

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

class Worker_Consumer {

private:
    int WORKER_ID = 0;
    int TRIGGER = 0;
    bool is_running1 = false;
    bool is_running2 = false;

public:
    //PRODUCER
    void startProducer(mutex &mtx, condition_variable &convar, std::deque<int> &sharedQ) {
        this->is_running1 = true;
        int count = 10;
        while (count > 0) {
            std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx);
            sharedQ.push_front(count);
            locker.unlock();
            convar.notify_one(); //wakes up thread2
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            count--;
        }
        this->is_running1 = false;

    }
    //CONSUMER
    void startConsumer(mutex &mtx, condition_variable &convar, std::deque<int> &sharedQ) {
        this->is_running2 = true;
        int data = 0;
        while (data != 1) {
            std::unique_lock<mutex>locker(mtx);
            convar.wait(locker);
            data = sharedQ.back();
            sharedQ.pop_back();
            locker.unlock();
            cout << "t2 got a value from t1:" << data << endl;
            }
        this->is_running2 = false;
    }

    bool isActive1() {
        return this->is_running1;
    }

    bool isActive2() {
        return this->is_running2;
    }
    //DEKLARATION VON GETTERN FUER KONSTANTEN
    Worker_Consumer() {
    }
};
```

THX and Greedings

Comment: `startProducer` and `startConsumer` are non-static member functions of `Worker_Consumer`. They need an actual `Worker_Consumer` object to be called on. Your program never creates such an object. Once it does, pass a pointer to this object as the second parameter of `std::thread` constructor, right after `&Worker_Consumer::startProducer`